# C# DDD доступ из Infrastructure к БД

Tags: c#, asp.net, ddd

Всем привет! Вот такой у меня вопрос. Пытаюсь осознать DDD и делаю web приложения на asp.net core. У менять есть функционал переводов, которые я получаю из БД и кэшу. Весь этот функционал я вынес в свой infrastructure. Теперь, по идеи я должен создать сервис, который будет получать данные из БД. Вопрос где это сервис создавать, там же в infrastructure? Я же не могу создать его в слое Application, а затем использовать в слое infrastructure?

Comment: Создать сервис (MyService) думаю лучше в Insfrastructure, а в Application создать (IMyService), поправьте если ошибаюсь.

Comment: Думаю не логично создавать IMyService в Application , так как есть вероятность того что в Application придется использовать классы из  Insfrastructure, и это уже будет не возможно, так как Insfrastructure будет зависеть от Application , а Application от Insfrastructure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если хотите отделить функционал доступа к данным, то его можно вынести в отдельную сборку, которую идеологически следует отнести к слою доступа к данным (Data Access Layer - DAL). К примеру, имя сборки может быть `MyProject.DAL` и содержать в себе интерфейс `IDALContext` и соответственно, его реализацию `DALContext`. Добавьте ссылку на эту сборку в `Infrastructure` и пользуйтесь интерфейсом `IDALContext`. Таким образом, весь код доступа к данным будет содержаться в конкретной реализации интерфейса `IDALContext`, а остальной код приложения будет пользоваться только этим интерфейсом.

Comment: Да, это все так как вы написали, так и есть. Но, я в приложении использую слой Application в котором я описываю, кроме другого, и сервисы, которые используют Context. В том и вопрос, что получается не правильно использовать сервисы из слоя Application в слое Infrastructure, для Infrastructure лучше писать свои сервисы использующие тот же Context, но только  внутри слоя Infrastructure?

Comment: Т.е. вы не пользуетесть контекстом БД напрямую, а создаёте дополнительные обёртки для него, чтобы использовать внутри `Application`?

Comment: Логично было быть писать что-то вроде `IDalContext (в слое DAL) -> DataAccessService (обёртка для IDalContext в Infrastructure/Domain) -> Repository (обёртка для DataAccessService из Infrastructure в слое Application)`. Но для начала подумайте, нужно ли вам столько дополнительных слоёв абстракций. Как правильно это актуально, если проект очень большой и сложный. Почему не восрользоваться контекстом БД напрямую из Application?

Comment: Вы меня извините, я наверно плохо объясняю что мне надо.
Смотрите, у меня есть контекст, я его использую в слое Application, например в этом слове есть сервис TranslationService в котором я использую Context. Теперь с слое Infrastructure у меня есть CustomStringLocalizer, в котором я хочу использовать TranslationService из Application. Вопрос, стоит ли так делать или в слое Infrastructure рядом с CustomStringLocalizer стоит создать TranslationService ?

Comment: Вы можете перенести `TranslationService` в `Infrastructure`?

Comment: Однозначно: использовать внутри `Infrastructure` то, что находится в `Application` - нелогично. Если часть когда, которая нужна Вам в `Application`, напрашивается быть использованной в коде `Infrascructure` (читай - `TranslationService`), то её следует перенести на уровень ниже, т.е. в `Infrastructure`.

Comment: То что я и хотел услышать, я так и думал, просто хотел услышать мнения более опытного человека, спасибо)))